# NoReverseMatch when rendering HTML

Tags: python, django

project/urls.py

```
(r'^notendur/', include('notendur.urls')),
```

app/urls.py

```
url(r'^options/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/', 'options', name='options'),
```

list.html

```
<form action="{% url "options" %}" method="post">
```

views.py

```
def options(request, pk):
    return render_to_response(
        'file_view.html',
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
        )
```

The error is caught at list.html. Can you spot what's wrong? I know that NoReverseMatch is a common error here, so I made sure to read previous posts on this. I have not found the source of my error.

What I want to do with this code is, when the form in `list.html` is activated, the options function takes the user to `file_view.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options URL needs a `pk` parameter, so you need to include it in the url tag.